# Parsing multiple HTML files located in one folder into one or multiple CSV using Python

Tags: python, html, csv, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have this Python code that parses data from multiple HTML files, and then I need to write them into one single CSV file (multiple files it's okay). But the problem is only the data from the last HTML file is being saved into CSV, I think this is due to overwriting as it's the same CSV file, Could you please help me solving this issue?

```
folder = "Folder Path"
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        print('Filename: {}'.format(fname))

        with open (fname, 'r') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser')
            info = soup.find_all('div' ,class_= 'panel-body')

            dataName = []
            dataPhone = []
            dataAdd = []
            dataCity = []

            for i in info:
                name = i.find('h2')
                address = i.find('p')
                city = i.find('strong')
                phone = i.find('label')
                
                dataName.append(name.string) 
                dataAdd.append(address.string)  
                dataCity.append(city.string)
                dataPhone.append(phone.string)

                print(dataName)
                print(dataPhone)
                print(dataAdd)
                print(dataCity)

                df = pd.DataFrame({"Name and Surname": dataName, "Address": dataAdd, "City": dataCity, "Number": dataPhone})
                df.to_csv('DataText.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally untested as I am busy at the moment but have a try at the following.
Basically, declare your lists before your loops then write out the CSV after exiting your loops.

```py
dataName = []
dataPhone = []
dataAdd = []
dataCity = []

folder = "Folder Path"
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        print('Filename: {}'.format(fname))

        with open (fname, 'r') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser')
            info = soup.find_all('div' ,class_= 'panel-body')

            for i in info:
                name = i.find('h2')
                address = i.find('p')
                city = i.find('strong')
                phone = i.find('label')
                
                dataName.append(name.string) 
                dataAdd.append(address.string)  
                dataCity.append(city.string)
                dataPhone.append(phone.string)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name and Surname": dataName, "Address": dataAdd, "City": dataCity, "Number": dataPhone})
df.to_csv('DataText.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick fix, I can confirm that it worked now :)